# Probability of a letter sequence from a sequence of $n$ random letters

Tags: probability

What is the probability of this specific sequence in a sequence of $n$ letters -

$A$, then any three letters, then $B$ and then $C$.

My idea: first treat this sequence of 6 bytes as one block. This could occur in $n-6$ places in n letters.
Then, amongst the 6 letters, the number of ways in which three of them are any letters and three are $A, B$ and $C$  specifically is $26^3$.
Then, we want a specific ordering for 3  of these 6 letters. The three bytes in the middle could be in any order, so the number of ways in which to order these 3 occurring  letters is 3!. The other 3 letters $A, B$ and $C$ occur in a specific order. Namely, $A, x , y , z, B, C$.

The total number of combinations of $n$ letters is $26^n$.

Therefore, this probability should be :

$$  \frac{(n-6)(26^3) 3!}{26^n}     $$

Is this correct?

Edit:

@NickPeterson pointed out that $n=6$ will give me a probability of 0.
Thus, I correct my formula to:

$$  \frac{(n-5)(26^3) 3!}{26^n}     $$

Comment: You're assuming that knowledge of whether one block matches doesn't impact knowledge of whether or not overlapping blocks match -- which seems unlikely.  You're also ignoring the possibility that there are multiple matches within the sequence writ large.

Also: try plugging in $n=6$.  It should give you a result with which you are not comfortable.

Comment: HI @NickPeterson - Could you elaborate a bit on your first two points? 
I should have mentioned that the probability of the letters occurring is independent. so knowledge of whether one block matches doesn't impact knowledge of whether or not overlapping blocks match.

Comment: @NickPeterson You're right about n=6 giving me a probability of 0. The (n-6) should be (n-5) to reflect 1 way of having a block of 6 letters if the total numbers of letters in the sequence is also 6. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** an answer.  I am posting this *long-winded comment* here **only** for legibility.

Clearly the answer will take the form $$\frac{T}{(26)^n}$$ where $T$ represents the
total # of ways that there is **at least one** occurrence of the satisfying sequence "A---BC" anywhere in the $n$-character string.

It is **dead wrong** to compute $T$ as $$(n-5) \times (26)^3.$$

This is because the occurrences of the satisfying sequence "A---BC" in one of the $(n-5)$ slots is **not** a mutually exclusive event.

This means (for example) that you could have partial strings that look like either "A-A-BCBC" (two occurrences) or "A---BCA---BC" (two occurrences).

One approach is to let $f(k)$ denote the # of ways that **exactly** $k$ occurrences of the sequence 
"A---BC" can occur.

The idea would then be to compute
$$T = f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + \cdots$$

As has been indicated in the comments, this is very difficult, because the assumption (for example) that the first 6 characters are "A---BC" affects whether another "A---BC" sequence can start in the first 6 characters.

Another approach is to count the # of ways that you can have an $n$-character string where the sequence "A---BC" does not occur.

If I was writing a computer program, I would spin through all 26 characters at each of the $n$ positions.  Then I would discount those situations where the character is a "C", the previous character (if any) is a "B", and the 5th character back (if any) is an "A".

In my opinion, this type of algorithm does **no good** re manually computing $T$ as a function of $n$.

It is tempting to reason that there are $\binom{n-5}{k}$ ways of distributing k "A"'s among the $(n-5)$ slots.  However, this merely disguises the problem that was broached in the first approach given in this *response*.  Some of the distributions of k "A"'s will *interfere* with each other.

I emphasize: this response is **not** an answer.  The only point to this response is to clarify the challenges in this problem.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the limitations of my solution and the assumptions that I made in trying to compute this. I could try reframing the problem a little and add a few more assumptions and 'givens' in the problem.